# rails: How do I disable protect_from_forgery in tests only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xss, integration-testing, capybara

I'm doing the integration tests of my rails app, and I'd like to test that custom POSTs with non-valid data (i.e. role=>'admin') are treated correctly - by being ignored or showing an error message.

Trouble is, the authenticity_token is a pain to setup.

Is there a simple way to deactivate protect_from_forgery when doing tests - or at least one test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your application controller

```
protect_from_forgery unless Rails.env.test?
```